# Apache .htaccess problem: No input file specified

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Can someone help me with this. I'm feeling like I've been hitting my head against a wall for over 2 hrs now.

I've got Apache 2.2.8 + PHP 5.2.6 installed on my machine and the .htacces with code below works fine, no errors.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|gfx|js|swf|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The same code on my hosting provider server gives me a 404 error code and outputs only: No input file specified. index.php IS there.
I know they have Apache installed (cannot find version info anywhere) and they're running PHP v5.2.8.

I'm on windows xp 64-bit, they're running some Linux and php in cgi/fastcgi mode.
Can anyone suggest what could be the problem?

PS. if that's important that's for CodeIgniter to work with friendly URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turned out I needed RewriteBase:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|gfx|js|swf|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Double-check the newline endings. Apache is kind of picky about them in .htaccess.
2. Turn off multiviews in .htaccess (Options -Multiviews) as read in [Sheepdog IT](http://www.sheepdogit.com/2008/07/29/no-input-file-specified-mod_rewrite-problem/)
3. You can always learn more about your environment using the phpinfo() function

Comment: Given that this is an Apache related problem, reading the output of phpinfo() will only serve to be a waste of time.

Comment: That would certainly help to get information about the Apache server version: "I know they have Apache installed (cannot find version info anywhere)"...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem trying to configure a friendly URL for my CodeIgniter project. I finally figured it out. Let's take a look at my apache2 configuration:

```
<Directory /home/hai/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The problem is at the line that said AllowOverride **None**. Change None to **All** and it works:

```
<Directory /home/hai/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Update: My system info:

- Server: Xubuntu 9.x (practically same as Ubuntu)
- Apache: version 2.2
- The configuration in question is in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

By the way, I am new to web design, php, and CodeIgniter (I just started php last week and CodeIgniter yesterday), so please kindly point out any mistake in my answer.

Update2: If afterward you get error code 500 instead of 404. It means you don't have the rewrite module enabled. Issue the following command to fix it:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```